# android - support libraries 23.2.0 cause app to crash

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library

My app works well with support libraries 23.1.0 or 23.1.1, but when i start using 23.2.0 it crashes on launch.
I use five support libraries, but the ones that seem to make it crash are these two:

> com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0
>
> com.android.support:design:23.2.0

I have this issue on my galaxy nexus (API 17) but not on my Nexus 7 (API 22).
Does anyone know what might be the problem?
Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ikarirobotics.aichordfinder"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.0'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

My layout is only a frame where i place the currently appropriate fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="HomeActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Using the debugger I was able to discover that the crash happens when the main activity calls setContentView():

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ikarirobotics.aichordfinder/com.ikarirobotics.aichordfinder.HomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

My activity extends AppCompatActivity and i make use of the support action bar. Any ideas on how to fix this problem? :(

Comment: gradle logs just say that the whole build was successful. I added info that i found using the debugger. It appears to be related to the toolbar.

Comment: are you using vector drawables?

Comment: No. Moreover, the first fragment is only a list of text entries and a FAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As predicted by some of the people here, the problem disappeared as i began using the 23.2.1 support libraries.
Thank you all for the support.

Comment: Did you mean to say 23.1.1 or 23.2.1? Because 23.2.1 does not work for me, even though I downloaded it

Comment: i mean 23.2.1. The problem appears to exist only in 23.2.0. Both 23.1.1 and 23.2.1 work fine (in my case at least). Did you change your gradle file after downloading?

Comment: I did change the gradle file of course, after downloading the 23.2.1 support library, to no avail. It just says it can't find it. I am also using the support library in chunks :cardview, :whatever....etc. Maybe that's why. Can you paste your gradle compile support lib line? If you only have one?

Comment: @Radu, as you see in my post, i have it in several lines. Now using 23.2.1:
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
}

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a drawable mutation bug as being worked on Google with the 23.2.0 release. [See the issue here.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201817) Reverting back to 23.1.1 should be fine until the next bugfix release.

Comment: Your link seems to be about spinners. Do you think it's the same issue?

Answer (score 4):

Same thing happens to me. I partially fixed it reverting to 23.1.1 on support:design.

Comment: if you happen to find a solution for using the 23.2.0 please post it here

Comment: I would not calling "fixing" and "reverting" the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

@CesarPim yes it is, I have a same problem for CheckBox, although I can fix that problem by creating abc_btn_check_material.xml inside drawable folder and adding following lines I can't be sure where it will break next. You can find drawables and selector code on this link: 
https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-plugin-appcompat/tree/master/platforms/android/appcompat/res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for the info. So is it safe to say that the problem is on google's side? My problem seems to be regarding my toolbar which has nothing except a title.. this is really weird.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the problem myself. A quick update via the SDK Manager seems to have solved the issue.

On a side note, none of my build.gradle dependencies actually used the 23.2.0, but I still received the error. Trying to 'downgrade' to 23.1.1 was not an option for me as I already was using that version.

Comment: What do you mean? What update via sdk? My problem exists when i use 23.2.0, not when i use 23.1.1