# Unmarshalling unknown type code 6881391 at offset 4752 After Upgrading to Support Libraries 23.2.0

Tags: android, android-support-library, parcelable, parcel

My app has been working well at Support Libraries 23.1.1. However, after upgrading to Support Libraries 23.2.0, it starts to crash. The crash happens when I navigate from an activity back to the main activity (for example, I open the about activity from main activity's actionbar menu, then press back button to go back to main activity, then it crashes).

The crash log is here:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.myapp.blah.blah, PID: 22124
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.myapp.blah.blah/com.myapp.blah.blah.ui.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@41d10870:
>   Unmarshalling unknown type code 6881391 at offset 4752 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@41d10870:
>   Unmarshalling unknown type code 6881391 at offset 4752 at
>   android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2087) at
>   android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2321) at
>   android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:249) at
>   android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1273) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1884)
>   at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:989) at
>   android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:961) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1145)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2407)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)?
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)? at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)?
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)? at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)? at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)? at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)? at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)? at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)?
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)? at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)?

The crash only happens if I set the developer debug option **"do not keep activities" on**. The crash does not happen if this option is off.

The crashes happens in debug mode where no Proguard is used.

I do not pass any parcels/bundles between the activities, and do not use startActivityForResult().

Crash happens on both pre and post Lollipop devices.

I found two similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647598/com-android-supportappcompat-v7-and-design-version-23-2-0-crash-parcel-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618098/android-support-libraries-23-2-0-cause-app-to-crash) which might (or might not) be related.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201836

Comment: @xDragonZ Thanks, starred the issue. I will probably revert back to 23.1.1 for now.

Answer (score 2):

> Unmarshalling exception when using SearchView with an id resource in
>   appcompat 23.2

Hi, it can fix by implement `onSavedInstance` and `onRestore` but don't use super. This strange behavior

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }
```