# File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-design-library

Recently `android support library` was updated to `23.2.0`. After downloading android sdk and updating android design support library into `23.2.0`, this error happens repeatedly. My project can't even be compiled. The complete error log says:

```
03-02 12:00:04.945 9324-9324/com.creditease.zhiwang.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.creditease.zhiwang.debug/com.creditease.zhiwang.activity.TabContainerActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5528)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2974)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.superGetDrawable(TintResources.java:48)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:44)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:184)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:91)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:74)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:210)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:119)
        at com.creditease.zhiwang.activity.BaseActivity.initToolBar(BaseActivity.java:300)
        at com.creditease.zhiwang.activity.BaseActivity.initToolBar(BaseActivity.java:265)
        at com.creditease.zhiwang.activity.TabContainerActivity.onCreate(TabContainerActivity.java:107)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:169) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5528) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
        Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:873)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2970)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.superGetDrawable(TintResources.java:48) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:44) 
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:184) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper.<init>(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:91) 
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.<init>(ToolbarActionBar.java:74) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:210) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:119) 
        at com.creditease.zhiwang.activity.BaseActivity.initToolBar(BaseActivity.java:300) 
        at com.creditease.zhiwang.activity.BaseActivity.initToolBar(BaseActivity.java:265) 
        at com.creditease.zhiwang.activity.TabContainerActivity.onCreate(TabContainerActivity.java:107) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:169) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1330) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5528) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This error was thrown by `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` whereas it didn't happen at `23.0.1` of `android design library 23.2.0`. Meanwhile according this log, I guessed this drawable was removed since `android design library 23.2.0`.

So, could someone told me why is this happening?

Comment: Did you checked the drawable folder if this file exists or not? If this file exists in the drawable folder, make sure that, the file name is all small letters and have no special characters excepts _. Also try to find the place where this resource is used.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, this one: `res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml`. Obviously, this drawable comes from `android design library`.

Comment: @Vishnu I only changed the version of `android design library` from `23.0.1` to `23.2.0`. All resources are OK.

Comment: Well, yeah  I can read the logcat. You didn't seem to specify what the "Caused by" line indicated in your question, so I was simply pointing it out

Comment: @cricket_007 `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` this line causes this at present. But, would it and how?

Comment: The full name of the XML file is (roughly, going off android naming scheme) "action bar compat, ice cream, action bar, back button, material"... So, that being said, it's the drawable for the back button on the toolbar, so it makes sense that line triggers the problem

Comment: I having same problem in `24.0.0`. How did you check the the file on `res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml` Idk how to get into this path. I'm also using `setSupportActionBar`

Comment: May it have something with `AppCompatActivity`? Is it ok for using it in newer versions of support library ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think you need to make changes in your `gradle`.

```
// Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

You’ll note this new attribute only exists in the version 2.0 of the Gradle Plugin. If you are using Gradle 1.5 you’ll instead use

```
// Gradle Plugin 1.5  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     // Stops the Gradle plugin's automatic rasterization of vectors
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  
  // Flag to tell aapt to keep the attribute ids around
  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```

I found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622438/update-android-support-library-to-23-2-0-cause-error-xmlpullparserexception-bin).

See [Support Vector Drawables and Animated Vector Drawables](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) in Android Support Library update.
I hope its help you.

Comment: And you need to use @style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar. to get it run lower version..

Comment: I need to install buildToolsVersion "23.0.3" to work

Comment: I get an error: `Error:(35, 0) Could not find property 'vectorDrawables' on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=ApiVersionImpl{mApiLevel=17, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=ApiVersionImpl{mApiLevel=23, mCodename='null'}`

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem for me... Still have Resource not found exception

Comment: Same issue, gradle 2.1, android libs 24.2.0. I patched gradle config but exception still appears on api19(4.4.4)

Comment: in which gradle to make these changes.. in module or project?

Comment: @Ananya : add in module level gradle into `android {..}` section.

Comment: @pRaNaY thanks for the info but the solution for me was to change appcompat version in dependencies and others like compile and targetsdk

Comment: @VictorPinto thanks a lot man it worked after following your suggestion.

Comment: @lvelius try adding static code block either in your application or activity class                        `static { AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true); }`

Comment: For me the trick was to add `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` to the onCreate() method.

Answer (score 10):

As per as the documentation of Google's support library for `24.0.0`, they have changed the vector drawable library to what it was before: 
Added `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled()` method to re-enable usage of vector drawables in `DrawableContainer` objects on devices running Android 4.4 (API level 19) and lower. See AppCompat v23.2 — [Age of the vectors](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.d2kkg0k4c)! for more information.

I faced the same issue and my SVG statelist drawables used in my project were working just fine till Marshmallow devices.

Later when I got the crash for the same in Android N, I realized that the svgs were a bit corrupted and contained characters like: � and this caused the crash.

But these were not reflected in Android Marshmallow and prior devices.

Make sure your vector drawable doesn't contain any of those characters as the way of parsing has been changed from the library 24.0.0. So vector drawables working fine till Marshmallow might not work in Nougat devices.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the info. Saved my time

Comment: Where did you add AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled()

Comment: It should be done before setting the content view. Preferably, in a `static` block.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (API 19, 4.4.2). Getting `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException`

Comment: Add this line in your Application class           AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);

Answer (score 6):

I solve this problem by updating my support library from

`'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'`
`'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'`

to the same dependencies of `23.2.1`.

When I met the problem, I had not made any changes in my module built by Android Studio.

So I was so confused then I tried to update android support library.
After updating, please remember to sync your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 5):

I solved the issue as follows:
Try with changing styles.xml to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

This is because if style requires ActionBar there are chances of not finding abc_back button but with no action bar problem is solved

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:  Replace the `com.android.support:design` version in `build.gradle` with one that works.  Find which version works by creating a new project from scratch in Android Studio and using the version from that.

I had this problem when I added a Navigation Drawer Activity from the **File**->**New**->**Activity** menu to an older project with Android Studio.

Android Studio added a dependency like so:
`compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'`
(I'm not sure of the exact version but it had '24' and 'alpha').

I then created a new dummy project, specifying a Navigation Drawer Activity in the new project wizard.  I noticed that the new project had a different dependency:  `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'`

So I took this dependency and put it in the first project, and the problem was solved.

Comment: You saved me. I changes mine into `compileSdkVersion 23`, `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'` and `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'`. So I looked for the latest 23 version of *appcompat-v7*. I was using version **24** but it didn't worked on Android 4.4.4

Comment: I've found that my code needs version 24 to work property. So I'm back trying to fix this vector drawable problem. If you get any tip let me know.

Comment: Essa deveria ser a resposta!!!

Answer (score 2):

**Source** - http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

> when using AppCompat with ImageView (or subclasses such as ImageButton
>   and FloatingActionButton), you’ll be able to use the new app:srcCompat
>   attribute to reference vector drawables (as well as any other drawable
>   available to android:src):

```
<ImageView  
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
  app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />
```

where you can define your **app** in your root element as

*xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"*

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue because my Manifest file had style that was defined only in v21 style. Not sure why it was pointing at this type of error but someone may find this helpful.