# Android Studio Upgrade Broke the Build

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm currently developing an app at my company, and making use of the AppCompatActivity activity. Upon researching another issue, I decided to update my Android Studio along with my build tools.

Now, my app crashes whenever it tries to load in any activity using AppCompatActivity on devices running Android 4.1.1 (which are the main devices we use). It works fine on 5.0 and 5.1.

Here is the error I am getting:

```
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016
```

This isn't the full error, but I cut out the uninteresting stuff (of course a bunch of classes have errors when you can't find a resource).

What drives me crazy is that when I go into the build/intermediates/res folder, I find all of the files that are supposed to be there.

Am I taking crazy pills?

Edit: The solution it points to is for vectorDrawables, not AppCompatActivity.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gillis.kenny.cxsort"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "3.32"

    }



    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
     }
}
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using now? What channel are you on: Stable, Beta, Canary?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File res/drawable/abc\_ic\_ab\_back\_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739743/file-res-drawable-abc-ic-ab-back-material-xml-from-drawable-resource-id-0x7f020)

Comment: Version 1.5.1 stable.

Comment: this is likely because you have put in a material theme and trying to run on non material OS version of android post your code

Comment: Also, the solution listed there doesn't work for me, and I can't comment because of lack of reputation. So, unable to ask for followup.