# gradle version incompatible (android studio 2.1 preview 1) <title editable>

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

today I upgraded my studio, and every latest sdkBuild version. 
now my build.gradle(app) configuration looks like this:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mydesign.rockstar.androidndemo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
```

}

now it says a newer version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7 than 23.2.0 is available: 24.0.0-alpha1 as well as for design: 23.2.0

its not working correctly, and my app crashing. toolbar error, style error, everything is not properly working. Please help me understand what the actual problem is?

Comment: Are you sure `buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc1"` is valid?

Comment: yup.. this is automatically generated.. i m not edited anything

Comment: Okay, I just tried myself and it downloaded.. What error does the logcat say when the app crashes? Also, try using `23.1.0` for the support dependencies, based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739743/file-res-drawable-abc-ic-ab-back-material-xml-from-drawable-resource-id-0x7f020)

Comment: i've seen this link before, its not working for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its working fine now, bcz i m just downloaded android support repository rev.28 and change both appcombat and design library to latest version. now its

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

this is latest version till now

what i learn is always use stable version of dependency. and this is what you can find it [here](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/)

Comment: Those are the latest stable versions.  But `24.0.0-alpha1` is newer.

Comment: I couldn't find 23.2.1 in the SDK Manager, latest available one is 23.0.0

Comment: @astrount that 23.2.1 is v7 support library.. this is not sdk tool version.. and you can find it here http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html