# Why does my android application gets closed after launch

Tags: android

I am new at android development .I get error unfortunately your application stopped .
My files are given below I am not able to figure with log cat . I have tried many solutions from stackoverflow but it did not resolve finally I have to put it here.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.umair.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**logcat**

```
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate: Exception while inflating <vector>
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:535)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:472)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:436)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:829)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:303)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:178)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at com.example.umair.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-19 10:32:46.265 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/VdcInflateDelegate:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 10:32:46.269 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-19 10:32:46.269 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4be9648)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.umair.myapplication/com.example.umair.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.umair.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.umair.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2091)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:695)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.umair.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:897)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:837)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2087)
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:695) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
03-19 10:32:46.289 1059-1059/com.example.umair.myapplication
```

Comment: The content.xml is not used in the code you pasted. Could you add the activity_main.xml?

Comment: The error is in your layout xml file, may be in `activity_main.xml` line # 17

Comment: Please see I have added it now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File res/drawable/abc\_ic\_ab\_back\_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739743/file-res-drawable-abc-ic-ab-back-material-xml-from-drawable-resource-id-0x7f020)

Comment: Please learn how to read your logcat and find the exact  error message. Your problem is you are using a bad version of the support library and your Gradle file needs changed