# EditText drwableLeft don't work with vectors

Tags: android, vector

In my app, I use **vector drawables** added in **support library 23.2** for display vector icons and it works perfectly but when I set the vector to drawableLeft of EditText it does not work in pre-lollipop android versions.
At runtime, **ResourceNotFound exception** occurs.

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File 
res/drawable/layer_ic_user.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200b3
```

This is my gradle configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.test"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    generatedDensities = []
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
       'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/res/assets/'] } }
  }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

EditText :

```
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_username_or_email"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/edit_text_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/layer_list_ic_user"
        android:textColorHint="@color/ColorBlackPrimary"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress|text"
        android:textColor="@color/ColorBlackPrimary"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_small"
        />
```

Comment: use `TextView#setCompoundDrawables`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739743/file-res-drawable-abc-ic-ab-back-material-xml-from-drawable-resource-id-0x7f020

Comment: @pskink how can i use TextView#setCompoundDrawables

Comment: how to use? just call it with 3 null Drawables and one non null Drawable

Answer (score 6):

You can add Vector Drawable in EditText programmatically. Make use of **VectorDrawableCompat** inorder to add drawableLeft/ drawableRight /drawableTop/ drawableBottom/ drawableStart/ drawableEnd.

**Steps:**

i. Remove `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/layer_list_ic_user"`

ii. If EditText is inside Activity:

```
EditText etUserName= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_username_or_email);
VectorDrawableCompat drawableCompat=VectorDrawableCompat.create(getResources(), R.drawable.layer_list_ic_user, etUserName.getContext().getTheme());
etUserName.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableCompat, null, null, null);
```

iii. If EditText is inside Fragment:

```
EditText etUserName= (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_username_or_email);
VectorDrawableCompat drawableCompat=VectorDrawableCompat.create(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.layer_list_ic_user, etUserName.getContext().getTheme());
etUserName.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableCompat, null, null, null);
```

For more information on VectorDrawableCompat Refer this  [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat.html)

Comment: Tried all the other solutions here, this is a simple and clean solution that actually works.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Since Android Support Library, revision 23.4.0

> Added AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled() method to re-enable usage of vector drawables in DrawableContainer objects on devices running Android 4.4 (API level 19) and lower. See [AppCompat v23.2 — Age of the vectors](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.44uulkfal) for more information.

You should add `static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}` to the top of your Activity.

You are using AppCompat 23.3. From [Android Developers](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/iTDmFiGrVne)

> For AppCompat users, we’ve decided to remove the functionality which let you use vector drawables from resources on pre-Lollipop devices due to issues found in the implementation in version 23.2.0/23.2.1. Using app:srcCompat and setImageResource() continues to work.

Comment: app:srcCompat is work fine with image view i want to use vector for drawableLeft of EditText

Comment: You can do it programmatically: VectorDrawableCompat.create()

Comment: In addition to `setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled`, I had to wrap the vector drawable in a selector, just to use it with `drawableRight`. As mentioned in [Age of the vectors](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.x4dvq5fe4): *The only rule is that the vector needs to be in a separate file*.

Answer (score 2):

I face this problem and solve it by putting the vector image inside layer-list drawable like that:
search_grey.xml

```
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_search_grey" /> 
</layer-list>
```

and in EditText:

```
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_grey"
```

Answer (score 2):

**AppCompatTextView** [now](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/androidx-rn#2018-dec-03-appcompat) supports `app:drawableLeftCompat`, `app:drawableTopCompat`, `app:drawableRightCompat`, `app:drawableBottomCompat`, `app:drawableStartCompat` and `app:drawableEndCompat` compound drawables, supporting backported drawable types such as `VectorDrawableCompat`.

Include this in your gradle file

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
```

In your TextView/ EditText you can use

```
app:drawableLeftCompat
app:drawableStartCompat
```

Answer (score 1):

Vector `drawables` won't work on pre lollipop devices as drawableLeft/drawableRight/..,  Don't set `drawableLeft` on `EditText xml`.
After initialising EditText set drawableLeft like below.

```
et_username_or_Email.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.layer_list_ic_user, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

chage the `extends Activity` to `extends AppCompatActivity` in the Activity class file and the problem solved.