# ActionBar customization not working with gradle and style changes

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-theme

I am Getting following error:
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020013

I am just Write following Code in style.xml:

```
   <style name="custom_actionbar_style" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/custom_actionbar</item>
        </style>

    <style name="custom_actionbar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/india</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@drawable/currancy2</item>
    </style>
```

And done following changes in Android Mainfest file.

```
defaultConfig{ vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true}
```

in gradle file and my gradle version is 2.10.
My Gradle file with following code

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
}
```

How to solve this  Error.

Comment: post your min and max API version you are using in app module build.gradle

Comment: min API version:16
max API version:24

Comment: post your build.gradle in the question

Comment: my default config in Gradle is
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 24
Iam not getting posting build.Gradle means?

Comment: just tell me what is support design library version in your build.gradle

Comment: You are using Holo themes, but your error hints that you need to be using material or AppCompat themes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File res/drawable/abc\_ic\_ab\_back\_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739743/file-res-drawable-abc-ic-ab-back-material-xml-from-drawable-resource-id-0x7f020)

Comment: i change my themes and even try 
defaultConfig{ vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true}
 these code still giving same error.

Comment: i added my app.gradle file in Question