# Why do I get a 'app:processDebugResources' error after trying to add the Support Design Library?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Android Studio had been working fine. But then I tried to add

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
```

I then got this error everytime I clean or build:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdks\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

So I tried removing it, but I still get the same error! I've been trying to fix it for hours but nothing I tried seems to work.

1. I tried the Make option in the Build menu
2. I have already tried File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
3. I tried changing the buildToolsVersion to lower versions
4. I tried changing the `appcompat-v7` import in gradle to lower versions
5. I tried putting `multiDexEnabled true`

Here is my current gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId [package]
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
}
```

I'll say it again, this is how it looked like before I added the support design library and it was working fine then.

Comment: I think there is more to the error that you aren't showing. The exception is above those lines in the Gradle build

Comment: I think I don't understand what you mean. What other situations does this error occur in?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618098/android-support-libraries-23-2-0-cause-app-to-crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618098/android-support-libraries-23-2-0-cause-app-to-crash)

Comment: Try running `lint` from the Gradle options and see if there are errors. `app:processDebugResources` is trying to compile resources like your XML views that lint will catch any misconfigured files

Comment: "I then got this error everytime I clean or build" -- please edit your question and post the **entire** Gradle console output, not just these lines. Your problem, as cricket_007 points out, appears higher in the Gradle console output.

Comment: Try to add `android {  
    ...
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
  ...
 }` in your gradle. It may helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Embaraasing. Thanks for your tips @cricket_007 and @CommonsWare. I tried removing the resources I added and removed the changes I have also made. It turns out I have this attribute enum in the `attrs.xml` file having the name of `true` and ` false.

```
<attr name=[attribute name]>
    <enum name="true" value="1"/>
    <enum name="false" value="2"/>
</attr>
```

Once I removed that everything became okay. Seems like I can't use certain words as the name. Curiously though, lint DID NOT notify me of this at any time I as editing and re-editing the file.

Nevertheless, thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome. If running the Gradle `lint` process pointed you to that problem, could you include the steps you took to find it? That might help others see similar problems